# Attach a filtered input in Weka datamining processes workflow

Tags: workflow, weka, data-mining

I'm creating a datamining process with Weka, so I have added an

-`ArffLoader`

selecting the datasource file, linking in the workflow this to a

-`ClassAssigner`

before pass the input to a classifier I need to use some filters, so I have linked the `ClassAssigner` out to a filter series. 
Now the problem is that seems I cannot link the last filter out to the classifier, when I click with right click of the mouse on `dataset` when I'm on `NominalToString` filter to attach its outo to `BayesNet` classifier, Weka show the arrow but this doesn't link to classifier. I have tried with different filter series, always the same problem.

What is wrong in the shown section of my workflow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the classifier you must add a component for the training set creation.

Try to attach the filtered input to a `CrossValidationFoldMaker` block (you can pick it from evaluation section) and link its out to `BayesNet` classifiers.